# Not able to download code deploy agent on aws linux ami

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to download the aws codedeploy agent on amazon linux ami. But it does not work. I made sure that role to access s3(full access) has been attached to the EC2 instance. Please find the command below:

wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install

```
--2020-07-25 03:59:12--  (try: 2)  https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install
Connecting to aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|52.216.248.88|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

aws s3 cp s3://aws-codedeploy-us-east-2.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/latest/install . --region=us-east-2

Also, noticed that aws-cli command to list s3 buckets is not working
aws s3 ls
What could be wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your instance running? In a private subnet or public? Does it have internet access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to connect to S3, there are many possible reasons these are detailed below:

- Ensure your security group allows outbound access to HTTPS (port 443) if you have restricted outbound access. By default all outbound access is allowed.
- If you have attached a non-default NACL to your instances subnet ensure that its outbound rules support port `443` as well as the [ephemeral ports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports).
- If your instance is using a public IP address ensure its route table has an [internet gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) for the `0.0.0.0/0` route (and `::/0` if you support IPv6).
- If your instance is private then ensure you have a [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html)/[NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) in place and attached to its subnets route table for the `0.0.0.0/0` route (and `::/0` if you support IPv6).
- If you're trying to restrict public internet connection, instead use a [VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html) for S3 and associate with your instances subnet.

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I enabled HTTPS traffic on port 443 for inbound and outbound rules both.

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)